# Custom generators visual studio database edition GDR not showing

Tags: sql, visual-studio

I'm trying to create a custom generator in Visual Studio team suite, I have installed the database edition GDR, I've followed the walkthroughs on MSDN for doing so for the GDR version (and triple checked my solution against the walkthrough) and downloaded projects from codeplex which illustrate the functionality. But no matter what I try the new item never appears on the drop down within a data generation plan. Has anyone else experienced the same problem and managed to resolve or know how to debug or log the loading of custom generators. Any pointers greatfully received.

Pete

Comment: I would provide more information.  Structure the question better.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to work this one out, it was to do with xxx.extensions.xml file which I was using.  The correct start to the file is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <extensions assembly="" version="1" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Data.Schema.Extensions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Microsoft.Data.Schema.Extensions Microsoft.Data.Schema.Extensions.xsd">
```

Not:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <extensions assembly="" version="1" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.Extensions" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Data.Extensions Microsoft.Data.Schema.Extensions.xsd">
```

As I found in some examples.

Hope this helps someone else!